# Canned models on GCP TPUs

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, deep-learning, google-cloud-tpu

Google's TPUs require you to port over your tensorflow Estimators to TPUEstimators, but what I can't seem to figure out is what kind of changes are necessary for the "canned" estimators (like the `DNNClassifier`) - it seems that only input function really needs changing to use the `tf.data.Dataset` but I could be wrong. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

TPU canned estimators are being worked on. But, to answer your question, I believe you just have to...

Things that need changing...

- Ensure optimizer is wrapped in a tf.contrib.tpu.CrossShardOptimizer
- tf.summary ops need to be removed or replaced with noops.
- Have Estimator's model_fn return TPUEstimatorSpec
- Enforce things like static batch size (which XLA requires I believe)

Might be a few other things.